# how to remove WebKitFormBoundary from uploaded file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to upload a Webvvt file using multipart/form-data, and the problem is that when I send the file to api, the file contain WebKitFormBoundary header and footer which corrupting the Webvvt format, as you can see below:

[image]

so can anyone please advise me with an approach to upload the file in other way, or how to remove the header and footer from the file.
my uploading request code is

```
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('selectedFile', new Blob([selectedFile], { type: 'text/webvtt' }));

    const headers = {
      Accept: ' application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4',
    };

    try {
      axios
        .put(`${uploadLink}`, formData, {
          headers,
        })
        .then((response) => {
          const resData = response.data;
          console.log(resData);
          ApplyText();
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const handleFileSelect = (event) => {
    setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);
    console.log(event);
  };




 <form method="PUT" encType="multipart/form-data" onSubmit={handleSubmit} action={uploadLink}>
        <input type="file" onChange={handleFileSelect} name="file_data" id="file" required />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
      </form>
```

Comment: Is this the latest Axios version - 0.27.2?

Comment: No I use version ^0.21.1"

Comment: Then you need to update to 0.27.2 since that version has a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I solved the issue by the following steps :
use a file reader to get the contents of the file that I want to "upload".
grab that content and put it straight into request body.

the code as following

```
const handleFile = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
      const content = e.target.result;
      setSelectedFile(content);   
  };


  const handleChangeFile = (file) => {
    const fileData = new FileReader();
    fileData.onloadend = handleFile;
    fileData.readAsText(file);
  };
```

Comment: Great job on your first answer. Can you please add some code snippets here.

Comment: yes sure I will include the code snippets in  the comment

Comment: can you please tell me how could you send it to the server without webkitformboundary

Comment: do as what I mentioned in the above comment, grab the content of the file by the above code and put it straight into the request body,